# HornetQHTWorkItemHandler cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: jbpm

I am trying to work on jBPM 5.4 and when I import the evaluation example I get the error.

**HornetQHTWorkItemHandler cannot be resolved to a type.**

I have installed all the mentioned plugins but still can't get rid of this error.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing the jbpm-human-task-hornetq jar in your classpath.

Did you use the jbpm-installer to install / set up your eclipse environment?  The jBPM library should in that case reference the jbpm-installer/runtime folder which should contain all necessary jars.

Alternatively, if you don't use the installer, you can just download the jbpm-bin artefact and create a jBPM runtime based on that folder.

Creating a new runtime from inside the plugin itself will not work in this case, as that only contains the most basic jars to get you started, it does not include the human task jars.

Kris

Comment: Hi Kris, thnx for your reply. First I setup the environment using plugins but it worked as well after creating a JBPM on the -bin folder.

Comment: Now I have done the setup again using the installer with noeclipse as I already have eclipse installed. I just had to change the path of eclipse in the build.properties file and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add this to your `pom.xml` if you're using Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbpm-human-task-hornetq</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```